# PHP Bitcoin validate from form

Tags: php, validation, post, bitcoin

I want to validate Bitcoin address from form. If someone enter invalid address it should echo "Please enter valid address". If address is valid, script should add this to database.
I have this code. I only need validate function.

```
      <form method="post" action="index.php">
        <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address">
        <input type="checkbox" name="terms"> <label for="terms">I'm accepting the <a href="#terms">terms of use</a></label><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
      <?php
        if(isset($_POST['address']) & isset($_POST['terms']))
        {
            include 'connect.php';
            $address=$_POST['address'];
            $date=date("Y-m-d");
            $request="INSERT INTO bitcoin (address, date) VALUES ('$address','$date')";
            mysqli_query($connect, $request) or die ("Error while writing to database! Try again...");
            mysqli_close($connect);
          }
       ?>
```

Comment: What makes an address valid?

Comment: There is something about this: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitcoin/address_validation
But i want to take it from form by POST. This function doesn't working for me.

Comment: from that example, put `validate()` and `decodeBase58()` in your file then use `validate($address)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being using https://github.com/LinusU/php-bitcoin-address-validator few times. No hustle working solution, with easy function caller to handle Bitcoin address validation.

> **isValid($addr, $version)**
>
> $addr: A bitcoin address $version: The version to test against,
>   defaults to MAINNET Returns a boolean indicating if the address is
>   valid or not.

**INSTALL**

Download from [GitHub](https://github.com/LinusU/php-bitcoin-address-validator) or `composer require linusu/bitcoin-address-validator`

**USE**

```
use \LinusU\Bitcoin\AddressValidator;  

// This is a valid address and will thus return true.
AddressValidator::isValid('1AGNa15ZQXAZUgFiqJ2i7Z2DPU2J6hW62i');
```

**USAGE ON CODE**

```
<?php 

    include 'connect.php';
    include 'LinusU\Bitcoin\AddressValidator.php';

    use \LinusU\Bitcoin\AddressValidator;  


    if(isset($_POST['address']) & isset($_POST['terms'])){
        $address=$_POST['address'];     
        if(AddressValidator::isValid($address)){
            // add
            $date=date("Y-m-d");
            $request="INSERT INTO bitcoin (address, date) VALUES ('$address','$date')";
            mysqli_query($connect, $request) or die ("Error while writing to database! Try again...");
            mysqli_close($connect);
        }else{
            // not valid
            throw new Exception('Invalid Bitcoin Address');
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: I'm beginner with PHP. How to use it exactly for my code? I need to download this, then $addr=$_POST['address']; include 'AddressValidator.php'; isValid($addr, $version);? I got Fatal error: Call to undefined function isValid()

Comment: Did you `include/require` the `AddressValidator.php` file? And have you added the command `use \LinusU\Bitcoin\AddressValidator;` ?

Comment: See updated answer - should be something like this, to get you started.